# Cosmos queries round trips in portal vs code

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've got a crosspartition query I'm running in Cosmos that I'm finding is taking vastly more round trips when run from code as opposed to running it in the Azure portal. In the portal the query only takes a single round trip, but using code it takes 80 round trips. I'm using the latest cosmos nuget package (Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.21.0). I'm running an identical query on the same container, so it feels like the queries should behave similarly. There are 19 results to the query, so it's not an issue with paging the results.

```
var iterator = myContainer.GetItemQueryIterator< myType>($"SELECT * FROM U WHERE contains(U.un, 'Steve')",
                requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
                {
                    MaxConcurrency = 0,
                    MaxItemCount = -1
                });

int count = 0;
while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    count++;

    var response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
}

Console.WriteLine($"Took ${count} round trips");
```

Is there anything I can do to reduce the number of round trips that the query makes? I've played with a few things in the QueryRequestOptions, but can't find anything that affects this.

Comment: What do you mean by `roundtrips`? How much data is returned in the Portal?

Comment: Round trips = calls to the database, I can see in Fiddler that the code is firing many requests to the db. The portal returns the same data (19 results, about 14Kb of data), and says it took 1 round trip.

Comment: What is the RU usage for the query and how did you measure the round trips from the portal?

Comment: Cost is around 2200 RUs and the portal literally tells you the number of roundtrips in the query stats.

Comment: I don't see that metric in my query stats. The only way I see roundtrips is my checking my network tab and counting the `POST` requests. 80 round trips seems excessive though. Even for the lowest possible RU/s unless it's under heavy load and most of the requests result in a `429`.